# chosen js performance issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

We have a result table(Grid) which has 12 column out of which two has single-select(`5 options only`) and a multi-select(`1 options only`) chosen drop-down. We throw the validation when the search result count is more than `2000`.

When search result are more than `200` and less than `2000`, the result table(Grid) got hanged with chosen.js plugin. If i removed it, it's working fine. It's look like chosen has to initialize for around 3*result count, which causing the hanging.

Is there is any way from which i can stop the page hanging or improve the `chosen.js performance`.

Comment: you should load the result while searching with ajax, im not sure if chosen.js support dat

Comment: It's not the issue with loading the options in the chosen.js, the main concern is when we have almost 2000 rows and every rows has three chosen dropdown, it just takes too much time to initialize the chosen 3*2000 times.